# Does Qt have any support for spherical coordinates?

Tags: c++, qt

Before reinventing the wheel, I wanted to ask - is there any built-in support for operations on spherical vectors?

My situation: I read values from accelerometer and I wanna calculate acceleration magnitude and direction. That's essentially acceleration as spherical vector. This is my code so far:

```
bool AccelPosition::filter(QAccelerometerReading* reading)
{
    QVector3D carthesian(reading->x(), reading->y(), reading->z());
    qDebug("Current device acceleration: [%f, %f, %f]", carthesian.x(), carthesian.y(), carthesian.z());
    return true;
}
```

I know well how to convert vectors to spherical and vice versa, but I wanted to know whether Qt can handle this or not. I'd also appreciate some appropriate method to do this on android platform.

Comment: (1) it's spelled "cartesian" and (2) you may want to use unit-magnitude vectors in 3D cartesian coordinates, and not 2D spherical coordinates. The latter representation makes little sense in this context.

Comment: @n.m.: Can you clarify the second point? For an accelerometer used to measure the orientation of a device, the direction of _g_ (gravity) is the main concern.

Comment: @n.m. I am not aware of any *"2D spherical coordinates"*. Sphere being 3D object cannot really represent 2D coordinate system. You might have been talking about polar coordinates, but I still don't understand where did you get that idea.

Comment: @TomášZato A sphere is a 2D object, not 3D. You only need 2 coordinates to represent any position on the sphere. Locally a sphere is similar to R^2. That's what 2D means. You are thinking of embedding a sphere in a euclidean space. Indeed you need 3D space for that. But the sphere itself is 2D. See any differential geometry textbook.

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure what are you trying to prove here or where did you get the idea that I'm embedding sphere on something. I think you're just one of these random comment flamers and I see no point to continue this discussion. [According to wikipedia, spherical coordinates are 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), so just go flame somewhere else, this is not a forum.

Comment: In terms of mathematics, n.m. is right. A sphere is a 2D surface embedded in a 3D space. You're not doing anything, a sphere just *is* that. Spherical coordinates can represent position on a sphere of any radius: they include both the position on the sphere *and* the radius of the sphere. Of course I don't see the point of bringing it all up, so if you're classifying it as a flame, I get you - but it's this curious corner case of a flame that is factually correct. I'd call it a case of Mondays :)

Comment: @KubaOber I got his point that e.g on globe navigation, you need two angles. But I explicitly mentioned magnitude (=radius) in my post, so the whole thing about sphere being 2D was totally irrelevant and confusing. I did not even mention sphere anywhere in my post, so this is just someone not having job and being annoying, sorry.

Comment: `QVector3D` has the `length()` member. It gives you the scalar acceleration -- one of the three spherical coordinates you're after. Unfortunately, you'll have to get the angles out of it yourself. You might also want to consider whether the Euler angles (the angle part of the spherical coordinates) will be useful to you later on. Euler angles are unfortunately not unique; poles will be necessarily problematic in this representation.

Comment: OK let me try again. You need a 3D vector as its magnitude and direction. The direction can be represented by two angular coordinates on the sphere, and these two coordinates together with the magnitude give yiu 3D spherical coordinates in space. But a pair of angles is not the only way to describe direction, and probably not the most convenient one. You can use a unit-length 3D vector for that. This representation is redundant (uses 3 numbers instead of 2) but is more convenient.

Comment: @n.m. Ok, I finally figured out you're talking about Quaternions. I actually ended up with them anyway because that's what OpenGL uses. But I don't see how would they be beneficial - they are completely obscure - I am actually porting some cube rotation code to C++ from javascript and it was way better without Quaternions.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about quaternions at all. Quaternions are convenient for representing spatial rotations (not sure what your problem with the cube was), but there are no rotations here. I'm talking about usual unit-length vectors in Euclidean 3-space.